Problem with TanStack and 'useIniniteQuery', 'isFetching' property always on true
I'm trying to learn how to use TanStack with TS, but I have various problems, I'm trying to execute this line of code, to obtain the data out of an API.
const { isLoading, isError, data, isFetching, refetch } =
    useInfiniteQuery<ResultUsers>({
      queryKey: ['users'],
      queryFn: fetchUsers as any,
      initialPageParam: 1,
      getNextPageParam: (lastPage) => lastPage.nextCursor,
    });
console.log(isFetching);
console.log(data);

isFetching always returns True, and data is always undefined.
I don't know what is the problem.
This is my fetching function.
interface Props {
  pageParam?: number;
}

export async function fetchUsers({ pageParam }: Props) {
  const seed = 'horse'; // Random seed.
  const apiLink = `https://XXXX.XX/api/?results=10&inc=email,picture,name,location&seed=${seed}&page=${pageParam}`;

  return await fetch(apiLink)
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) throw new Error('Error when connecting to DB');

      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      const resultUsers = data.results.map(
        ({ email, picture, name, location }: Result) => {
          return {
            id: email,
            picture: picture.thumbnail,
            firstName: name.first,
            lastName: name.last,
            country: location.country,
          };
        }
      );

      const resultPage = Number(data.info.page);

      return { resultUsers, resultPage };
    });
}

I have tried different solutions from different posts but I cant get it to work.
